# Python loop web scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have ran a scraper successfully for one individual match URL, when trying to use a for loop to run this scraper over the range specified, the scraper only works for one game. Am I missing code here to tell python to store the results and move on looping back on the code
ideally I want to store each match to the data frame, move on to next match and then finish up the all the data in the one dataframe

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import pandas as pd

for id in range(16376,16379):
    understat = f'https://understat.com/match/{id}'
    res = requests.get(understat)
    # parsing the webpage, use .content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
    scripts = soup.find_all('script')

    # get only shots data, and strip data so we only have json data

    strings = scripts[1].string
    index_start = strings.index("('") + 2
    index_end = strings.index("')")
    json_data = strings[index_start:index_end]
    json_data = json_data.encode('utf8').decode('unicode_escape')
    data1 = json.loads(json_data)

    x = []
    y = []
    xg = []
    team = []
    data_home = data1["h"]
    data_away = data1["a"]

    for index in range(len(data_home)):
        for key in data_home[index]:
            if key == "X":
                x.append(data_home[index][key])
            if key == "Y":
                y.append(data_home[index][key])
            if key == "xG":
                xg.append(data_home[index][key])
            if key == "h_team":
                team.append(data_home[index][key])

    for index in range(len(data_away)):
        for key in data_away[index]:
            if key == "X":
                x.append(data_away[index][key])
            if key == "Y":
                y.append(data_away[index][key])
            if key == "xG":
                xg.append(data_away[index][key])
            if key == "a_team":
                team.append(data_away[index][key])

    # create the df

    colnames = ["x", "y", "xg", "team"]
    df = pd.DataFrame([x, y, xg, team], index=colnames)
    df = df.T

...
```

Comment: I think the problem is creating the `df` inside the for loop. Everytime the loop starts, a new dataframe is created with only the values of the game within that loop. Try creating the dataframe before the loop and let the `for` loop add values for each `match id` as it loops through the range.

Comment: Are you certain that you're getting HTTP 200 from each of the requests? I don't see any check. Also, your two inner for loops are very strange

Comment: @DarkKnight - the code works fine for one match,  unfortunately it seems to be stopping at one match and not looping again

Comment: Create the list outside of the loop for starters and convert the whole thing to a dataframe at the end of the for loops and at the end I mean after the for loop is over. You're rewriting the list every time you try to run a "id" so to speak